# Instagram and Signed Requests - Pulling Hashtag

Tags: php, api, instagram

Since I have it set to enforce signed requests, I'm running into some difficulty pulling media with a hashtag. I'm able to retrieve with other endpoints but not with the following "/tags/snowy/media/recent"

I'm not sure how or where I can get the 'min_tag_id','max_tag_id' without unsetting the "enforced signed requests" even when I do just change the "enforcing rule temporarily (which i ultimately don't want to) and put the parameters to generate the Instagram sig it still gives me the response below.

```
{
     code: 403,
     error_type: "OAuthForbiddenException",
     error_message: "Invalid signed-request: Signature does not match"
}
```

My code to generate the signed request is below. I feel like the issue lies in the parameters that I need to set to return the correct signature.

```
    function generate_sig($endpoint, $params, $secret) {
      $sig = $endpoint;
      ksort($params);
      foreach ($params as $key => $val) {
        $sig .= "|$key=$val";
      }
    return hash_hmac('sha256', $sig, $secret, false);
    }

    $endpoint = '/tags/snowy/media/recent';
    $params = array(
      'access_token' => 'TOKEN',
      'count'   => '10',
       'min_tag_id' => '',
       'max_tag_id' => ''
    );
    $secret = 'SECRET';
    $sig = generate_sig($endpoint, $params, $secret);

    $url = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/snowy/media/recent?access_token='. $access_token .'&sig='. $sig;
    echo $url;
```

Comment: `min_tag_id`,`max_tag_id` is available in the API response "pagination"

Comment: I can't receive a response cause I have a signed response and can't get it to generate the correct sig because I don't have the min and max Id

Comment: try: if value is empty dont add it to `$params` and then generate `$sig`

Comment: You need all the param values in order to generate the sig

Comment: `min_tag_id`,`max_tag_id`,`count` are optional